# Referencing assemblies that use NuGet packages from a project that also uses some of these packages

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, nuget, .net-assembly

I have a complex library `A` that consists of several c# projects producing the following assemblies:

- A.Core
- A.Caching
- A.Logging
- A.MongoDb

The library is written by me, and I have full access to its source code.
It depends on several NuGet packages, let's say they are:

- mongocsharpdriver
- EnterpriseLibrary.Caching
- EnterpriseLibrary.Logging

*These libraries (MongoDb driver and EntLib) are not installed in GAC.*

I also have a web project `B` and I want to use library `A` in it as a reference to a DLL (not including projects into solution `B`).
The web project depends on several NuGet packages, among them:

- mongocsharpdriver
- EnterpriseLibrary.Logging

*Versions of these packages in solutions `A` and `B` do not match as they are not developed synchronously. Library `A` was developed a year ago and used as is since then.*

**Question:** what is the proper way to distribute library `A` so that:

1. Any solution could use it even if lib `A` dependencies are not referenced.
2. If a solution has its own versions of lib `A` dependencies, they do not conflict.

**My current approach:**

1. From my solutions, I reference the four dlls: `A.Core, A.Caching, A.Logging, A.MongoDb`.
2. Then I add all its NuGet dependecies to the solution, if they are not present.
3. It breaks sometimes as solution `B` uses mongocsharpdriver version 1.5 and lib `A` uses version 1.1 (the versions are not that compatible).

So, what shall I do?
What will be the correct way of dealing with conflict 'references vs. references of references'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to manage shared references is to [create your own NuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) for library A which, among other things, defines any dependencies (including versions) that library A relies on. If you don't want to publish library A to the public NuGet feed, you can [host your own feed](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).

NuGet has some [complex dependency resolution rules](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dependency%20Resolution) that will attempt to locate a dependency version that is compatible with your project and its dependencies. Unfortunately, this still won't solve your problem in point 3 above, where your solution and its dependent library use mutually incompatible versions of the same external dependency. In this case, you'll just have to re-work either your solution B or library A so that they use the same version of mongocsharpdriver.

Comment: Create my own package is a great option I was not aware of. I believe it is the best thing that can be done here. Thank you!